# Using ellipse or ellipsis gone wrong

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm creating a simple program that gets name, age and favorite number/s. The problem is that this exception appears when user chooses to input more than 1 favorite number.

[image: exception]

Please help me to solve this problem that still uses ellipse in testing class --> favnum2 method.*

testing class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testing{
public static Scanner input;


public static void main(String[] args){

    boolean choicerepeat=true;
    int favnumoftimes;

    while(choicerepeat==true){
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        testing2 obj1 = new testing2();
        String name="";
        int age=0;
        favnumoftimes=0;
        double favnum=0, favnumarr[]=new double[999];
        boolean choice1;

        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("What is your age? ");
        age = input.nextInt();

        obj1.message1(name);
        obj1.message2(age);

        System.out.print(name+" do you only have one favorite number? (If yes type 'true' else 'false' - NOTE: lowercase only) ");
        choice1 = input.nextBoolean();

        if(choice1==true)
            favnum1();
        else{
            System.out.println("How many favorite numbers do you have "+name+"? ");
            favnumoftimes = input.nextInt();
            for(int a=0;a<favnumoftimes;a++){
                System.out.print("Enter favorite number "+ (a+1) +": ");
                favnumarr[a]=input.nextDouble();
            }

            for(int a=0;a<favnumarr.length;a++){
                favnum2(favnumoftimes, favnumarr[a]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Do you want to restart the program? (true(Yes) else false(No)) ");
        choicerepeat = input.nextBoolean();

    }
}

public static void favnum1(){
    System.out.print("Enter favorite number: ");
    double favnumholder1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Your favorite number is "+favnumholder1+" ." );
}

public static double favnum2(int favnumoftimesholder,double...favtemphold2){
    System.out.print("Your favorite numbers are ");
    for(int a=0;a<=favnumoftimesholder;a++){
        System.out.print(favtemphold2[a]+", ");
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

testing2 class

```
public class testing2{
public static String message1(String nameholder){
    for(int a=0;a<nameholder.length();a++){
        char strholder = nameholder.charAt(a);
        if(Character.isDigit(a)){
            System.out.println("Names don't have numbers... ");
            break;
        }
        else continue;
    }
    System.out.println("\nHi "+nameholder+"! Welcome to my simple program. ");
    return nameholder;
}

public static int message2(int ageholder){
    System.out.println("Your age is "+ageholder+" years old? Oh my goodness. ");
    System.out.println();
    return ageholder;
}
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you past stacktraces here instead of linking them as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that varargs create new arrays with a length equal to the number of parameters passed. Thus `double...favtemphold2` will create a new array `favtemphold2` and since you only pass 1 element (`favnum2(favnumoftimes, favnumarr[a]);`) that array will have length 1.

You might want to either pass more elements or the entire array, i.e. `favnum2(favnumoftimes, favnumarr);`. Since `double...` is basically syntactic sugar for `double[]` they are equal and passing a double array for a double vararg will work.

A warning for future use of varargs though: be carefull with `Object...` since arrays are objects as well.

Comment: Thanks sir Thomas. :D